# error in connecting to sql from C# windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I have a form in c# which get user and pass and a form that shows the informations of employees also two tables are in sql server which i want to show in Gridview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String UserId = textBox1.Text;
    String passwrd = textBox2.Text;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.,SQL2014;Database=MyTamrin;uid=Sa;password=Sa123;");
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception r)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
    }

    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();

        sqlcomm.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.Empp WHERE fldUserName = @snum AND fldPassword = @pass";
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@snum", UserId);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", passwrd);
        if ((Int16)sqlcomm.ExecuteScalar()==1)
        {
            Userinfo mainform = new Userinfo();
            mainform.Show();

        }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: _"what is the problem??"_ yes, tell it us. Btw, dont show your db login credentials in cleartext in the internet.

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please read the [FAQ]'s and [ask]. This will please @TimSchmelter and help you to write better questions. Good luck!

Comment: I need a proffesional to see my source code and correct it in a minute.I want to email it .(The c# code)

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the:

```
sqlComm.Connection = myConnection;
```